# How to change the size and colour of a TextView?

Tags: java, android, colors, textview

While making my first android app I've got some problems with changing the size and color of TextView with Java code.

Comment: Please provide some code what you have done till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the text color

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.<name_of_color>));
```

To change the text size

```
text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);
```

Comment: thanks, I will try this and answer in comments about the results